# Error -java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Web application is deployed, but hits following error message.  I am doing with cxf RESTFUL webservice and trying to encode/decode using JSON. I have already added logging library to my WEB-INF but it still shows the following error. I have added Commons Logging 1.1.1 lib in WEB-INF/Lib folder.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.<init>(ContextLoader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.createContextLoader(ContextLoaderListener.java:57)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What library did you add and where in WEB-INF did you put it? Spring doesn't rely on commons logging (it uses log4j) so something else is looking for it.

Comment: Did you put it in WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: I have added Commons Logging 1.1.1 lib in WEBINF/Lib folder

Comment: If your folder is truly named `WEBINF` then I think I see your problem...

Comment: @Paul- No WEB-INF is the folder name

Comment: Did you open your war file and check that the library is contained within?

Comment: Also the folder should be named `WEB-INF/lib` with a lowercase `l`, not uppercase like in your question. Mentioning this just in case.

Comment: @Paul Spring does rely on Commons Logging (the API), not log4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up in updating the CXF jar to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the class `LogFactory` itself but something it depends on.

If you have a `ClassNotFoundExceptions` it means that the class is not found by the classloader, usually meaning that the jar containing this class is missing.

But in your case you have a `NoClassDefFoundError`, which means that while loading the class above it cannot find a required definition.

Comment: So how did you end up fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

The classes are missed at the time of execution of test in classpath of the project
s
Solution : add in your pom
         
             commons-discovery
             commons-discovery
             0.5
             test